# Google recaptcha based on user session

Tags: php, session

I am looking to verify human visitors by showing Google recaptcha to users after counting their session. Lets say after 15 page views of same session show verification form.

Issue is if they bot refresh page with validating session value is +1 and form gone so no validation

Code I have is

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['views'])) { 
$_SESSION['views'] = 0;
}

$_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+1;

if ($_SESSION['views'] == 15) { ?>
<div id="" class="overlay">
<div class="popup">
      <form>
      </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?php }
```

How to sort this issue that user must verify before refreshing or doing anything else

Comment: The bot can ignore session cookie and so you are not counting the pageviews.

Comment: Its not solution... any help to solve issue that they can not see next page untill verified